# Android layout refreshes when a picture of an ImageView is changed

Tags: android, android-layout, scrollview

I have a layout with a `ScrollView`.When I change the picture of an `ImageView` or Text of TextView, layout refreshes and screen goes to the top.I Think the problem is in ScrollView.

**XML file:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/sv2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#FFEEEEEE"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="0dp"
        tools:context="hamrahyper.rayanpejuhanparse.jamshidiasl.hamrahyper.Main3Activity">

        <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#FFEEEEEE">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText3"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageViewx"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageViewx"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:ems="10"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:hint="جستجو در همراهایپر"
                android:inputType="textPersonName"
                android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
                android:textColorHint="@android:color/background_light"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/imageView1"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageViewx"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView1"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/editText3"
                android:layout_alignRight="@+id/editText3"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/editText3"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:padding="5dp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:srcCompat="@mipmap/i1" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageViewx"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView10"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:srcCompat="@mipmap/icart2" />

            <ViewFlipper
                android:id="@+id/viewFlipper"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:autoStart="false"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editText3">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView4"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                    android:scaleType="fitXY"
                    app:srcCompat="@mipmap/btn1" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView5"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                    android:scaleType="fitXY"
                    app:srcCompat="@mipmap/btn2" />
            </ViewFlipper>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView16"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:text="دسته بندی محصولات"
                android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/viewFlipper" />

            <HorizontalScrollView
                android:id="@+id/sc1"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="220dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView16">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:elevation="5dp"
                        app:cardElevation="5dp">

                        <RelativeLayout
                            android:id="@+id/rl1"
                            android:layout_width="150dp"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:background="@android:color/background_light"
                            android:padding="5dp">

                            <ImageView
                                android:id="@+id/im1"
                                android:layout_width="120dp"
                                android:layout_height="120dp"
                                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                                app:srcCompat="@mipmap/icon1" />

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/tv1"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_below="@+id/im1"
                                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                                android:padding="5dp"
                                android:text="..."
                                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                                android:textSize="14sp" />

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/tx1"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                                android:layout_below="@+id/tv1"
                                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                                android:padding="5dp"
                                android:text="..."
                                android:textColor="@android:color/holo_green_dark"
                                android:textSize="12sp" />
                        </RelativeLayout>
                    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

                    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                        android:elevation="5dp"
                        app:cardElevation="5dp">

                        <RelativeLayout
                            android:id="@+id/rl2"
                            android:layout_width="150dp"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:background="@android:color/background_light"
                            android:padding="5dp">

                            <ImageView
                                android:id="@+id/im2"
                                android:layout_width="120dp"
                                android:layout_height="120dp"
                                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                                app:srcCompat="@mipmap/icon1" />

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/tv2"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                                android:layout_below="@+id/im2"
                                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                                android:padding="5dp"
                                android:text="..."
                                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                                android:textSize="14sp" />

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/tx2"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                                android:layout_below="@+id/tv2"
                                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                                android:padding="5dp"
                                android:text="..."
                                android:textColor="@android:color/holo_green_dark"
                                android:textSize="12sp" />
                        </RelativeLayout>
                    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

                    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                        android:elevation="5dp"
                        app:cardElevation="5dp">

                        <RelativeLayout
                            android:id="@+id/rl3"
                            android:layout_width="150dp"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:background="@android:color/background_light"
                            android:padding="5dp">

                            <ImageView
                                android:id="@+id/im3"
                                android:layout_width="120dp"
                                android:layout_height="120dp"
                                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                                app:srcCompat="@mipmap/icon1" />

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/tv3"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_below="@+id/im3"
                                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                                android:padding="5dp"
                                android:text="..."
                                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                                android:textSize="14sp" />

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/tx3"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_below="@+id/tv3"
                                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                                android:padding="5dp"
                                android:text="..."
                                android:textColor="@android:color/holo_green_dark"
                                android:textSize="12sp" />
                        </RelativeLayout>
                    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

                    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                        android:elevation="5dp"
                        app:cardElevation="5dp">

                        <RelativeLayout
                            android:id="@+id/rl4"
                            android:layout_width="150dp"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:background="@android:color/background_light"
                            android:padding="5dp">

                            <ImageView
                                android:id="@+id/im4"
                                android:layout_width="120dp"
                                android:layout_height="120dp"
                                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                                app:srcCompat="@mipmap/icon1" />

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/tv4"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                                android:layout_below="@+id/im4"
                                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                                android:padding="5dp"
                                android:text="..."
                                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                                android:textSize="14sp" />

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/tx4"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                                android:layout_below="@+id/tv4"
                                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                                android:padding="5dp"
                                android:text="..."
                                android:textColor="@android:color/holo_green_dark"
                                android:textSize="12sp" />
                        </RelativeLayout>
                    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

                    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                        android:elevation="5dp"
                        app:cardElevation="5dp">

                        <RelativeLayout
                            android:id="@+id/rl5"
                            android:layout_width="150dp"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:background="@android:color/background_light"
                            android:padding="5dp">

                            <ImageView
                                android:id="@+id/im5"
                                android:layout_width="120dp"
                                android:layout_height="120dp"
                                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                                app:srcCompat="@mipmap/icon1" />

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/tv5"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                                android:layout_below="@+id/im5"
                                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                                android:padding="5dp"
                                android:text="..."
                                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                                android:textSize="14sp" />

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/tx5"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                                android:layout_below="@+id/tv5"
                                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                                android:padding="5dp"
                                android:text="..."
                                android:textColor="@android:color/holo_green_dark"
                                android:textSize="12sp" />
                        </RelativeLayout>
                    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

                    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                        android:elevation="5dp"
                        app:cardElevation="5dp">

                        <RelativeLayout
                            android:id="@+id/rl6"
                            android:layout_width="150dp"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:background="@android:color/background_light"
                            android:padding="5dp">

                            <ImageView
                                android:id="@+id/im6"
                                android:layout_width="120dp"
                                android:layout_height="120dp"
                                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                                app:srcCompat="@mipmap/icon1" />

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/tv6"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                                android:layout_below="@+id/im6"
                                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                                android:padding="5dp"
                                android:text="..."
                                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                                android:textSize="14sp" />

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/tx6"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                                android:layout_below="@+id/tv6"
                                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                                android:padding="5dp"
                                android:text="..."
                                android:textColor="@android:color/holo_green_dark"
                                android:textSize="12sp" />
                        </RelativeLayout>
                    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
                </LinearLayout>
            </HorizontalScrollView>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView6"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/sc1"
                app:srcCompat="@mipmap/btn5"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView17"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:text="پرفروش ترین محصولات"
                android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView6" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView19"
                android:layout_width="18dp"
                android:layout_height="18dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                android:background="@mipmap/bdr3"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:paddingLeft="1dp"
                android:paddingTop="1dp"
                android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark"
                android:textSize="10sp"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView10"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView10"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:paddingBottom="6dp"
                android:paddingLeft="3dp"
                android:paddingRight="3dp"
                android:paddingTop="6dp"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:srcCompat="@mipmap/menuicon" />

        </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

I think the problem is `ScrollView`, so I set a focusable property of `ScrollView` to false but the problem not resolved.What is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this line  `android:fillViewport="true"`

```
<ScrollView

     android:fillViewport="true">
</ScrollView>
```